# Firebase android push notification doesn't work on other device

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

sorry for my bad english.

I sending push notification from my codeigniter web to android app, I have 3 devices to test it.

My first device, it works well for me. 
And then in my second and third device my android didn't receive any message.

I tried to send notification from my firebase console, then I choose target is user segment with my package name. All of my devices receive the message.

Then I tried to send notification using topic, which is my topic is global. Only my first device receives the message.

Here's my code :

```
 public static final String TOPIC_GLOBAL = "global";
 public static final String REGISTRATION_COMPLETE = "registrationComplete";
 public static final String PUSH_NOTIFICATION = "pushNotification";


mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                // gcm successfully registered
                // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                displayFirebaseRegId();

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received

                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //  txtMessage.setText(message);
            }
        }
    };


 private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

    Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),regId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), regId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```